# [Error]: Returned Object is not JSON Serializable

Tags: python, mysql, django, serialization

**How to serialize date time object?**

I am trying something like this.

```
my_date_time = json.dumps(list_of_objects)
```

list_of_objects variable is the response from raw query to MYSQL.

Please suggest how to serialize the response having some datetime object in it. **Thanks!**

Comment: You have to manually convert the `datetime` object to a string or number; JSON doesn't have native date/time types.  Without knowing more about your context, I can't say exactly what would be appropriate.

Comment: i m new to python, please can you let me know how can i manually do this.

Comment: Please tell us what the program that will read this JSON expects to find when it encounters dates.

Comment: Somewhere in `values` is a `datetime` object (probably from `cursor.fetchall()`) - can you tell us more about the structure of `values["data"]`?

Comment: yah, value["data"] is a type of dictionary. which contains such values like: values["data"]=(one row), (second row), and so on...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thanks to all of you, finaly i have made the solution using CAST(expr AS type) method.

The CAST() function takes an expression of any type and produces a result value of a specified type

SELECT name, CAST(date AS CHAR(10)) FROM table WHERE condition.

thanx to Zack and Hennele Kormano.